# Making buttons disappear in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm doing a coding project at school and I'm trying to set up functions for my buttons
but when i run the code the buttons run the commands without being clicked and they don't dissapear because the button mentioned in the function that hides them doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
#Parent Window Setup
GoodChefWindow = Tk()
GoodChefWindow.title("Welcome To GoodChef")
GoodChefWindow.geometry("600x500")

#Displaying Company Logo
Logo=PhotoImage(file="LogoV2.gif")
LogoCanvas=tkinter.Canvas(GoodChefWindow,height=150, width=600)
LogoCanvas.create_image(300,75,image=Logo)
LogoCanvas.pack()

#Pickup and Delivery buttons
def Delivery_Clicked():
    Delivery=Tk()
    Delivery.title("Delivery Options")
    Delivery.geometry("400x333")
    Remove_Buttons()

def PickUp_Clicked():
    Delivery=Tk()
    Delivery.title("Pick Up Options")
    Delivery.geometry("400x333")
    Remove_Buttons()

def Remove_Buttons():
    MenuButtonsFrame.destroy()

def Buttons(MenuButtonsFrame):    
    DeliveryIcon=PhotoImage(file="Delivery_Icon.gif")
    PickUpIcon=PhotoImage(file="Pick_Up_Icon.gif")
    MenuButtonsFrame = LabelFrame(GoodChefWindow, text="Order")
    MenuButtonsFrame.pack()
    DeliveryLabelFrame = LabelFrame(MenuButtonsFrame)
    DeliveryLabelFrame.pack(side=RIGHT,expand="yes")
    PickUpLabelFrame = LabelFrame(MenuButtonsFrame)
    PickUpLabelFrame.pack(side=LEFT,expand="yes")
    DeliveryButton = tkinter.Button(DeliveryLabelFrame,bg="red",
                                    fg="yellow",compound="left",
                                    image=DeliveryIcon,height=40,
                                    width=120,text="Delivery",
                                    command=Delivery_Clicked())
    PickUpButton = tkinter.Button(PickUpLabelFrame,bg="red",
                                  fg="yellow",compound="left",
                                  image=PickUpIcon,height=40,
                                  width=120,text="Pick Up",
                                  command=PickUp_Clicked())
    DeliveryButton.pack()
    PickUpButton.pack()

Buttons()
```

Comment: This code doesn't run (missing argument in call to `Buttons`). Please post the actual code you're running. Also it would be nice to adhere to [Python naming guidelines](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Your code is doing something fundamentally wrong, which can cause several types of undesirable side effects. You should never create more than a single instance of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, you need to create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to rethink your approach in my opinion, here is the way I would do what you have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

#Parent Window Setup
GoodChefWindow = Tk()
GoodChefWindow.title("Welcome To GoodChef")
GoodChefWindow.geometry("600x500")

#Displaying Company Logo
Logo=PhotoImage(file="rd.gif")
LogoCanvas=Canvas(GoodChefWindow,height=150, width=600)
LogoCanvas.create_image(300,75,image=Logo)
LogoCanvas.pack()

#Pickup and Delivery buttons
def Delivery_Clicked():
    Delivery=Toplevel()
    Delivery.title("Delivery Options")
    Delivery.geometry("400x333")
    Remove_Buttons(MenuButtonsFrame)

def PickUp_Clicked():
    Delivery=Toplevel()
    Delivery.title("Pick Up Options")
    Delivery.geometry("400x333")
    Remove_Buttons(MenuButtonsFrame)

def Remove_Buttons(MenuButtonsFrame):
    MenuButtonsFrame.destroy()

DeliveryIcon=PhotoImage(file="rd.gif")
PickUpIcon=PhotoImage(file="rd.gif")
MenuButtonsFrame = LabelFrame(GoodChefWindow, text="Order")
MenuButtonsFrame.pack()
DeliveryLabelFrame = LabelFrame(MenuButtonsFrame)
DeliveryLabelFrame.pack(side=RIGHT,expand="yes")
PickUpLabelFrame = LabelFrame(MenuButtonsFrame)
PickUpLabelFrame.pack(side=LEFT,expand="yes")
DeliveryButton = Button(DeliveryLabelFrame,bg="red",
                                fg="yellow",compound="left",
                                image=DeliveryIcon,height=40,
                                width=120,text="Delivery",
                                command=Delivery_Clicked)
PickUpButton = Button(PickUpLabelFrame,bg="red",
                              fg="yellow",compound="left",
                              image=PickUpIcon,height=40,
                              width=120,text="Pick Up",
                              command=PickUp_Clicked)
DeliveryButton.pack()
PickUpButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

This should help? if not speak out! you could also make more tk windows (toplevel isn't necessary).